# Sealing leaking cracks in concrete lanai roof that is also an upstairs balcony

Tags: concrete, leak, crack

First, I want to apologize for the length of this. I like to think I'm a reasonably competent DIYer but this one *may* be out of my wheelhouse. (and I'm not even sure what type of contractor I'd call for the repair)

Here's the situation: My patio behind my house has a lanai (roof) covering it that also doubles as the upstairs patio/balcony off the master bedroom. It is wood framed with a plywood deck and then it appears that about 3" of concrete was poured on top of that. There is a stucco ceiling on the bottom.

A little more than a year ago or so, we discovered we had a termite problem and as a result had to do some structural repairs to include replacing the LVL beam that holds up the lanai/upstairs patio. In the process of (unevenly) jacking the lanai up a little bit to replace the beam, they cracked the concrete upstairs in a few places. The contractor assured me that 'oh we'll squeegee in some epoxy and you'll be good go' -- they also replaced some areas of concrete where we took the old railing down (which are just raw concrete at this point, not painted or anything.)

Long story short, the cracks (and maybe unpainted areas of concrete) are a problem. When it rains, I see water dripping through the stucco ceiling below.

Any advice on where to start with this? Is there a pragmatic (read: cost effective) solution that doesn't involve replacing the entire upstairs patio? Something like a skim coat over top or something?

Comment: Call the contractor and tell them you were not good to go after all? You MIGHT get satisfaction, you might not.

Comment: Ok, so let's consider this question a plan B in the event that I don't.  Thanks for your comment.